# Improve efficiency of data.table by group

Tags: r, performance, data.table, grouping

I'm looking for ways to improve the efficiency of the following calculation

```
jaccard3 <- function(a,b) sum(a %in% b)/length(unique(c(a,b)))

temp <- dlong[, {print(.GRP)
  x = pp[pnum == origpat, iid]; y = pp[pnum == ref.pat, iid]; .("overlap" = sum(x %in% y), "inv.jac" = jaccard3(x,y))}, by = idx]
```

The two data.tables that I am relying on look as follows

```
sapply(dlong, class)
  origpat   ref.pat       jac   originv    refinv       idx 
"numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "integer" "integer" "integer"
```

and

```
sapply(pp, class)
       pnum   inventors      pryear     pr_date    inv_patc         iid 
  "integer" "character"   "integer"      "Date"   "numeric"   "integer"
```

My objective is thus to look for the inventors in origpat and ref.pat (they are stored in `pp` as character in column `inventors` and as integers in `iid` [I am assuming that integer matching should be faster than character matching.

The structure of `dlong` is such that the values for `origpat` and `ref.pat` will appear multiple times (`origpat` may appear up to 500 consecutive times) but every combination of `origpat` and `ref.pat` is unique. `dlong` has about 11 million rows, each one defined by a unique `origpat ref.pat` combination whereas `pp` has about 230,000 rows, each one defined by an unique `pnum iid` combination.

I add a very short extract of the data [updated after comment]

```
 dput(dlong[1:100])
structure(list(origpat = c(4246034, 4246034, 4246034, 4246034, 
4246034, 4246034, 4246034, 4246034, 4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 
4247592, 4248614, 4248614, 4248614, 4248614, 4248614, 4248614, 
4248614, 4248614, 4248761, 4251278, 4251278, 4251278, 4251278, 
4251278, 4251278, 4251278, 4251278, 4251278, 4253719, 4253719, 
4267550, 4273567, 4273567, 4273567, 4273567, 4273567, 4273567, 
4273568, 4273568, 4273568, 4273568, 4273568, 4273568, 4273569, 
4273569, 4273569, 4273569, 4273569, 4273569, 4273586, 4273586, 
4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 
4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 
4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 
4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 
4273813, 4273813, 4277285, 4277286, 4277286, 4277286, 4277286, 
4277286, 4277286, 4277286, 4277286, 4277286, 4277286, 4277286, 
4277286, 4277286, 4277286, 4280829, 4280829), ref.pat = c(4293439, 
4277285, 4328022, 4248614, 4297139, 4395271, 4294190, 4285730, 
4431982, 4303735, 4309520, 4315970, 4358181, 4478622, 4312654, 
4293439, 4406517, 4478623, 4277285, 4328022, 4377675, 4293439, 
4277285, 4328022, 4248614, 4297139, 4395271, 4294190, 4285730, 
4246034, 4491379, 4534098, 4338590, 4358181, 4478622, 4312654, 
4406517, 4478623, 4248614, 4358181, 4478622, 4312654, 4406517, 
4478623, 4248614, 4358181, 4478622, 4312654, 4406517, 4478623, 
4248614, 4293439, 4277285, 4328022, 4248614, 4297139, 4395271, 
4294190, 4285730, 4246034, 4251278, 4339174, 4282035, 4285731, 
4311504, 4277286, 4298389, 4362819, 4360567, 4295872, 4302235, 
4331770, 4282022, 4304584, 4344670, 4297193, 4292080, 4284686, 
4385802, 4311529, 4314031, 4310651, 4534948, 4293439, 4293439, 
4277285, 4328022, 4248614, 4297139, 4395271, 4294190, 4285730, 
4246034, 4251278, 4339174, 4282035, 4285731, 4311504, 4358181, 
4478622), jac = c(0.0714285714285714, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 
0.25, 0.2, 0.2, 0.25, 0.5, 0.0909090909090909, 0.0714285714285714, 
0.25, 0.142857142857143, 0.125, 0.2, 0.25, 0.0714285714285714, 
0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 
0.142857142857143, 0.0714285714285714, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 
0.25, 0.2, 0.2, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.2, 0.0769230769230769, 0.125, 
0.2, 0.25, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.25, 0.125, 
0.2, 0.25, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.25, 0.125, 
0.2, 0.25, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.25, 0.0714285714285714, 
0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.25, 0.2, 0.2, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.25, 
0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.333333333333333, 1, 0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
1, 0.25, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.5, 0.125, 0.333333333333333, 
1, 0.142857142857143, 0.0769230769230769, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.1, 0.111111111111111, 0.0714285714285714, 
0.0714285714285714, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.25, 0.2, 0.2, 0.25, 
0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.125, 0.2), idx = 1:100), sorted = "origpat", class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000000000f4a1ef0>)
```

and

```
    dput(pp[1:75])
structure(list(pnum = c(4246034, 4247592, 4248614, 4248761, 4251278, 
4253719, 4262069, 4262069, 4262069, 4262575, 4267550, 4273567, 
4273567, 4273568, 4273568, 4273569, 4273586, 4273586, 4273586, 
4273586, 4273813, 4275419, 4277285, 4277285, 4277285, 4277286, 
4277286, 4277322, 4279234, 4279234, 4280829, 4281094, 4281094, 
4282003, 4282003, 4282022, 4282022, 4282035, 4282578, 4282578, 
4282648, 4282648, 4282648, 4283218, 4283439, 4283439, 4283439, 
4284213, 4284319, 4284686, 4284872, 4285730, 4285730, 4285731, 
4286061, 4286061, 4286061, 4286061, 4286978, 4286978, 4288356, 
4288356, 4288470, 4288470, 4289517, 4289517, 4289522, 4289522, 
4289859, 4289859, 4290100, 4290586, 4290586, 4290843, 4290843
), inventors = c("03868264-1", "04070526-2", "04204850-2", "03862079-1", 
"03902910-1", "04253719-1", "03862861-2", "04262069-2", "04262069-3", 
"04216691-1", "04128775-2", "04273567-1", "04273567-2", "04273567-1", 
"04273567-2", "04273567-2", "03879694-2", "03912524-1", "04116704-4", 
"04116704-5", "04273813-1", "03871022-1", "04057435-1", "04277285-2", 
"04277285-3", "03973976-1", "04179638-3", "03958052-2", "03878357-1", 
"03886401-1", "04280829-1", "04039504-1", "04281094-2", "04236065-1", 
"04236065-2", "04204851-1", "04282022-1", "04282035-1", "04169243-1", 
"04282578-2", "04282648-1", "04282648-2", "04282648-3", "04273567-2", 
"04063973-3", "04283439-1", "04283439-2", "04284213-1", "03964009-1", 
"04086089-2", "04229692-1", "03858548-1", "04046545-1", "04282035-1", 
"03868304-1", "04039387-1", "04039387-2", "04149936-2", "04126436-1", 
"04286978-2", "04288356-1", "04288356-2", "03979604-1", "03980915-3", 
"04126436-1", "04286978-2", "04126436-1", "04286978-2", "03900416-1", 
"04070526-2", "04290100-1", "03958052-2", "03978316-2", "04290843-1", 
"04290843-2"), pryear = c(1980L, 1980L, 1979L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1977L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1979L, 1979L, 1980L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1978L, 1978L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1977L, 1977L, 1977L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1978L, 1979L, 1979L, 1980L, 1978L, 1978L, 1978L, 1978L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1978L, 1978L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L), pr_date = structure(c(3665, 
3723, 3364, 3681, 3672, 3679, 3728, 3728, 3728, 2818, 3676, 3693, 
3693, 3693, 3693, 3693, 3826, 3826, 3826, 3826, 3791, 3710, 3298, 
3298, 3298, 3701, 3701, 3686, 3298, 3298, 3784, 3623, 3623, 3261, 
3261, 3770, 3770, 3697, 3728, 3728, 3735, 3735, 3735, 3693, 2913, 
2913, 2913, 3840, 3693, 3812, 2934, 3564, 3564, 3697, 3169, 3169, 
3169, 3169, 3836, 3836, 3925, 3925, 3266, 3266, 3836, 3836, 3836, 
3836, 3805, 3805, 3735, 3686, 3686, 3701, 3701), class = "Date"), 
    inv_patc = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
    3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
    1, 1, 2), iid = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
    11L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
    20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
    32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 13L, 41L, 42L, 
    43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 35L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 
    54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 54L, 55L, 54L, 55L, 60L, 2L, 
    61L, 25L, 62L, 63L, 64L)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -75L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000000000f4a1ef0>)
```

Based on my calculation and the code used above, running the 11 million lines would take about 85 hours. 
One improvement to the code

```
temp <- dlong[, {print(.GRP)
      x = pp[pnum == origpat, iid]; y = pp[pnum == ref.pat, iid]; .("overlap" = sum(x %in% y), "inv.jac" = jaccard3(x,y))}, by = idx]
```

Would probably be to not cycle through each index `idx` but cycle first through `origpat` (so that we can keep x fixed for up to 500 rows) and then for fixed `origpat` cycle through all the different `ref.pat` values. However, I only know how to do this with a loop and then the whole point of data.table gets lost.

Any suggestions to enhance speed?

Thanks

Comment: In your example data there are no cases where `pnum == origpat` and/or `pnum == ref.pat`. Please update your example data.

Comment: I gave the example merely to show the data structure. The question really relates to a higher efficiency solution for an already working formula. Not sure how useful it would be to provide 10,000 rows of my dataset?

Comment: I didn't say you need to include 10k rows. I just ask to provide example data where at least for some of the cases `pnum == origpat` and/or `pnum == ref.pat`. That will make it a lot easier to demonstrate whether the code is working correct or not.

Comment: I did so as I updated the example after your comment. I basically simply setkey(dlong, origpat) and setkey(pp, pnum) to ensure some overlap

Answer (score 0):

You can give the following a try.

1. Join `dlong` with `pp` on `origpat`.
2. Then join that result with `pp` again on `ref.pat` and calculate the denominator in your jaccard function.
3. Then inner join the first result with `pp` on `ref.pat` and `iid` to calculate the nominator in the jaccard function.
4. Finally calculate the jaccard value.

sample data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
nDlong <- 11e6
npat <- 230e3
dlong <- data.table(
    idx=1:nDlong,
    origpat=sample(npat, nDlong, replace=TRUE),
    ref.pat=sample(npat, nDlong, replace=TRUE))
pp <- data.table(pnum=1:npat, iid=sample(npat/5, npat, replace=TRUE))
```

code + timings:

```
system.time({
    opat <- pp[dlong, on=c("pnum"="origpat"), allow.cartesian=TRUE]
    jacc <- pp[opat, on=c("pnum"="ref.pat"), allow.cartesian=TRUE][, 
        .(setlen=uniqueN(c(i.iid, iid))), by=.(idx)]
    olaps <- pp[opat, on=c("pnum"="ref.pat", "iid"="iid"), nomatch=0L][, 
        .(overlaps=.N), by=.(idx)]

    ans <- olaps[jacc, 
        .(idx, jaccVal=replace(overlaps, is.na(overlaps), 0) / setlen), 
        on=.(idx)]
})

#   user  system elapsed 
# 154.10    1.14  163.09
```